# Rails 4 - How to select data from a table if in another table is not a specific record?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

I have this model schedule:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :closed_questions
end
class ClosedQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And I am trying to fetch all questions for a user that this user didn't check as closed.

Example:

```
ID | Question
1  | Question A
2  | Question B
3  | Question C
4  | Question D
```

`User 1` checked question with ID `3` as closed. How to get the output of question IDs `1, 2, 4`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try something like this:

```
user = User.find(1)
Question.where.not(id: user.closed_questions.pluck(:question_id))
```

Note that prior to Rails 4 you might see this written as:

```
user = User.find(1)
Question.where("id NOT IN (?)", user.closed_questions.pluck(:question_id))
```

Comment: Just to improve the code you could achieve same with `Question.where.not(id: user.closed_questions.pluck(:question_id) `

Comment: Thanks.  Updated with your suggestion.